# Exporting access report to word

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, export

i'm working with ms access and i have a report wich i want to exporte in Word when complete.
I'm facing problem with a text box while exporting. The report looks like this

[image]

The problem is i cannot know how much would be written in that textbox , 2,3,4..word pages. And i cannot create a text box extremley big to hold every possible size cause i would export blank pages with only the top (title and logos). How can i make it dynamically expandable?

Heres the report with text, there are many many 'aaa...' up not shown , it was just to make you see the line of '1' to show that they dont appear after export

[image]

And here is the exported result

[image]

Comment: Textbox controls have a `CanGrow` property (under Format tab) which auto-grows to accommodate entered text. Try setting it to yes.

Comment: Did , nothing changed

Comment: Please screenshot the Access report **with** text content (that you claim cuts off) and the Word document output.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to generate the report in Access AND in Word, with the Word version based on the Access report format? I can imagine you'd get a better and more efficient result writing the data directly to a prepared Word template...